# Transparent textures in OpenGL ES 1.1 for iOS

Tags: textures, transparency, blending, opengl-es-1.1

I've read other posts regarding similar issues and seem to have tried everything that stood there, but still didn't manage to achieve the desired effect.

What I want is to display arrows on the screen to give the user the possibility to rotate the selected object by pressing on them. My idea was to create a couple of png files with a transparent background and to show them as textures.

The corresponding code is spread among several source files, but I think the relevant parts are as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    void *image;
} TextureData;


NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:arrowFile ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

TextureData *texData;
texData->width  = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
texData->height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
texData->image = malloc(4*texData->height*texData->width);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(texData->image, texData->width,
    texData->height, 8, 4*texData->width,colorSpace,
    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, texData->width, texData->height));
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, texData->height - texData->height);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, texData->width, texData->height),
    image.CGImage);
CGContextRelease(context);

[image release];
```

With the obtained TextureData structure the textures are generated

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, arrowTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texData->width, texData->height,
    0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texData->image);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
```

And during the rendering phase I proceed as follows:

```
vec2 texVertices[6];
vec3 vertices[6];

texVertices[0] = vec2(1.0f, -1.0f);
texVertices[1] = vec2(0.0f, -1.0f);
texVertices[2] = vec2(0.0f,  0.0f);
texVertices[3] = vec2(1.0f, -1.0f);
texVertices[4] = vec2(0.0f,  0.0f);
texVertices[5] = vec2(1.0f,  0.0f);

vertices[0] = vec3( 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f);
vertices[1] = vec3(-0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f);
vertices[2] = vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
vertices[3] = vec3( 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f);
vertices[4] = vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
vertices[5] = vec3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(vec3), &vertices[0]);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(vec2), &texVertices[0]);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, arrowTexture);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

The result that I see is my arrow on the black background, and I am quite puzzled about it. Would appreciate any help/ideas/suggestions on this, thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out the root cause of why I was getting black background instead of correct blending. Just post it here, in case somebody faces the same issue:
I forgot to render objects w.r.t to their distance, the farthest first, and as a result, OpenGL was blending my texture with glClearColor, which was black. Evident, when I look at it now, but it almost made me desperate. Another thing; glDisable(GL_LIGHTING) was not so important although it did make my arrows look nicer. The missing part was to switch off the depth testing with glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS).